# PHP - сформировать строку из нескольких по группе

Tags: php

В цикле получаем значения переменных.

```
foreach ($rows as $r) {

foreach ($array_1 as $a) {

echo $r['id'].' '. $a.'<br>';
}
}
```

На выходе получаем вот такой список:

```
396 зеленый
396 рядовой
396 эффективный
396 утолщенный
396 купить кирпич
396 яйцо
401 рядовой
401 эффективный
401 утолщенный
401 купить кирпич
401 яйцо
403 рядовой
403 эффективный
403 утолщенный
403 купить кирпич
403 яйцо
404 рядовой
404 эффективный
404 утолщенный
404 купить кирпич
404 яйцо
```

Не могу сообразить как можно собрать его в строку, чтобы в каждой строке были только значения у который определенный $r['id']

Т.е чтобы получилось вот так:

```
396, зеленый,рядовой,эффективный,утолщенный,купить кирпич, яйцо
401, рядовой, эффективный, утолщенный, купить кирпич, яйцо
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Соберите во внутреннем цикле во временный массив и выведите его через implode

```
foreach ($rows as $r) {
   $temp = [ $r['id'] ];
   foreach ($array_1 as $a) {
       $temp[] = $a;
   } 
   echo implode(', ', $temp) .'<br>';
}
```